# If $\pi $ is a normal number, is $\tau $ one?

Tags: constants

If $\pi$ is a normal number, would that imply that $\tau =2\pi $ is also a normal number? If so, why? Something tells me that it should be, but I have no idea how to prove it. If all digits of $\pi$ were either $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$, the proof is self-evident. Obviously, every decimal digit appears in $\pi$, so that's where that self-evident proof will fall apart.

Comment: "If all digits of $\pi$ were either $0,1,2,3,$ or $4$, the proof is self evident".  How do you figure?  If all the digits of $\pi$ were $0,1,2,3,4$, then $\pi$ wouldn't be normal. I have no idea what you're going for; does $\pi$ being normal mean something besides the normal definition?

Comment: Can't a number be normal if only some of the digits appear in it in some given base?

Comment: No.  A number is normal if (and only if) all digits (and all finite sequences of digits) appear with equal frequency.

Comment: All digits that appear in it or all digits used to represent a given base?

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a [rational multiple of any normal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties) (with respect to a base $b$, such as $b = 10$) is also normal (with respect to the same base).

The number $\tau = 2 \pi$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$, and visa versa.  So, $\tau$ is normal if and only if $\pi$ is normal.

Comment: Here is a print reference: http://books.google.com/books?id=mnY8LpyXHM0C&pg=PA76&dq=%22every+nonzero+rational+multiple+of+a+normal+number+is+normal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MQAmU7zLM8GE0AG1yID4Aw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22every%20nonzero%20rational%20multiple%20of%20a%20normal%20number%20is%20normal%22&f=false

Answer (score 4):

Well according to wikipedia this statement:

"If x is normal in base b and q ≠ 0 is a rational number, then x⋅q is normal in base b."

has been proven by Wall.

Wall, D. D. (1949), Normal Numbers, Ph.D. thesis, Berkeley, California: University of California.